# Guardar archivo en una carpeta inexistente

Tags: python-3.7, mkdir, fastapi

disculpen, estoy desarrollando una app en python y necesito guardar archivos en el servidor por medio de python, este es mi codigo actual:

```py
for file in files:
            filename = "/img/"+lv_id+"/"+file.filename
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
            with open(filename, "wb") as myfile:
                lv_content = await file.read()
                myfile.write(lv_content)
                myfile.close()
        return ({"status":"ok", "message":"Images upload successfully", "id":lv_id})
```

Yo tengo un id y un file name que recibo de la carga, una clase de lista, pero me da error porque no puedo guardarlo ya que la carpeta no existe y he visto el makedirs en otro ejemplo, uso python 3.7

Comment: Según lo que leo, estas guardando en una carpeta `/img` que está directamente en la raíz del disco. Probablemente quieras decir `img/`.

Comment: Estabas cerca de lo correcto, aunque tambien le cambie algo mas, y fue la forma de cambiar el directorio

Answer (score 0):

La solucion al error es el siguiente:

```py
try:
        for file in files:
            if not os.path.exists("img/"+lv_id):
                os.makedirs("img/"+lv_id)
            with open(os.getcwd() + "/img/" + lv_id + "/" + file.filename, "wb") as myfile:
                lv_content = await file.read()
                myfile.write(lv_content)
                myfile.close()
        return ({"status":"ok", "message":"Images upload successfully", "id":lv_id})
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return ({"status":"error","message":"The upload failed"})
```

Comment: Con "with open" no necesitas `myfile.close()`; el archivo se cierra solo. Tampoco necesitas `os.getcwd()`; basta con `img/`.

Comment: Vale, muchisimas gracias, ya lo corrijo